# What does "took to engineer" mean in this sentence from the New York Times?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I want to ask meaning of a sentence especially a phrase I have seen New York Times:

> "President Trump’s vituperative tweet against Iran late on Sunday showed his determination to use the same approach that he **took to engineer** a diplomatic breakthrough with North Korea"

As I understand he would take similar action against Iran. But I am confused about "took to engineer". What exactly does it mean? Is that an idiom?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial research efforts; for example, looking up *[engineer](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/engineer)* in the Collins Dictionary finds the meaning *If you engineer an event or situation, you arrange for it to happen, in a clever or indirect way*, which explains its use here. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by user9570789 is correct, but I wanted to go into a little more detail:

There are two phrases in this expression, which can be used separately.  The first is "take steps"

> [**take steps**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+steps) (v): To do what is necessary to prepare for or begin doing something.

Examples:

> They **took steps** to prevent another fire in their hotel, by doing such things as installing automatic extinguishers in every room.
>
> "What **steps** is the administration **going to take** to ease taxes on the average citizen?" the reporter asked.

Second, "engineer", used as a verb:

> **[engineer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/engineer)** (v): Skillfully arrange for (something) to occur.

Some examples:

> In the movie, the twins cleverly **engineered** a family crisis to bring their estranged parents back together.
>
> The prosecutor alleged that the defendant **engineered** a series of forged press releases in order to manipulate the company's stock price.

Put together, you get this variation on, "Trump took steps to engineer a diplomatic breakthrough."

Answer (score 1):

An Engineer is someone who helps to design/plan/build things.  Used as a verb, it means to "design/plan/build something".  So, they're simply saying "...showed his determination to use the same approach that he took to design a diplomatic.."